# i want my create view and list view on the same page

Tags: python, django

I want my create view and list view on the same page and in my list view i only want login users post to show . With this code my create view works but in place of list view it does not show anything and it also does not show any error. How can i fix this. Thank you
this is my views.py:-

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView
from .models import simpleList
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
# Create your views here.


class CreateList(CreateView):
    model = simpleList
    template_name = 'create_list.html'
    fields = ('title', )
    success_url = reverse_lazy('create_list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def ListListView(request):
        current_user = request.user
        user_list = simpleList.objects.filter(author=current_user)
        return user_list
```

this is my html:-

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Create{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Add</button>
</form>

<h2>simpleList</h2>
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">S.No</th>
            <th scope="col">Task</th>
            <th scope="col">Done</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<div>
    {% for simpleList in user_list %}
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead style="display: none;">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">S.No</th>
                <th scope="col">Task</th>
                <th scope="col">Done</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <div>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="table-primary">
                    <th scope="row">{{ simpleList.pk }}</th>
                    <td style="max-width: 100px;  word-break: break-all;">
                        {{ simpleList.title }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </div>
    </table>
</div>

{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from both `CreateView` and `ListView` and override `get_queryset` method to filter by author.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView
from .models import simpleList
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
# Create your views here.


class CreateList(CreateView, ListView):
    model = simpleList
    template_name = 'create_list.html'
    fields = ('title', )
    success_url = reverse_lazy('create_list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        current_user = self.request.user
        queryset = queryset.filter(author=current_user)
        return queryset
```

In the template(`for` template tag) instead of using `user_list` you can use `object_list`.

```
{% for simpleList in object_list %}
```